# What character traits define Ibsen’s Brand?

Tags: character-analysis, scandinavian-languages, henrik-ibsen, brand-ibsen

(I am not asking this for a school assignment. I’m not in school.)

I have not read Brand carefully. I want an introductory sense of if the content of the play accords with my understanding so far.

I would like to believe that Brand is an ambiguous, complicated character who captures an interesting dynamic of human psychology that we may see at times in people we know. Brand is uncompromising, willful, driven, adheres firmly to principle, and morally intent. But Brand’s belief in what is right and wrong, and his willingness to “go it alone” and be true to himself, result in situations where compromise would appear more realistic, to an outside observer. Brand is not a villain, but he actually suffers from grandiosity - he doesn’t have a realistic assessment of human capability or outcomes in certain situations. His tendency to paint life in big brushstrokes and stark black-and-white color cause incidents of unnecessary chaos, and suffering, both for people around him, and for himself, though he is willing to shoulder his own burdens he has resolved for himself.

Is this accurate?

Or is my idea of the theme missing part of the text?